# even after submit of form my fields are not inserted into database using php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am new to php. When form is submitted the data has to store on database. When I started to code it worked fine but later on data is not inserted into database I was trying to insert form details to database but unable to insert on regular basis. Sometimes,data is stored on database but most of the times, it doesn't store. so please help me....

php version:7
and MySQL database

**form**

```
<form role="form" class="register-form"  method="post" action="aluminiregdb.php">
    <center><h2>Alumni Registration</h2></center>
    <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="roll_number" id="roll_number" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Roll Number" tabindex="3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="4">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ">
                <select class="form-group form-control input-lg" name="SelectInstitution">
                    <option value="select">Select Institution</option>
                    <option value="sdes">Sree Dattha institute of Engineering and science (SDES)</option>
                    <option value="sdgi">Sree Dattha group of istitutions Integrated Campus (SDGI)</option>
                    <option value="sdip">Sree Dattha institute of Pharmacy (SDIP)</option>
                    <option value="sdbn">Sree Dattha Brindavan institute of Teacher Education (SDBN)</option>
                    <option value="sdbd">Sree Dattha Brindavan institute of Diploma (SDBD)</option>
                    <option value="bits">Brindavan institute of Teacher Education (BITS)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ">
                <select class="form-group form-control input-lg" name="SelectInstitutiondegree">
                    <option value="select">Select Degree Obtained</option>
                    <option value="B.Tech">B.Tech</option>
                    <option value="M.Tech">M.Tech</option>
                    <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
                    <option value="Polytechnic">Polytechnic</option>
                    <option value="B.Pharm">B.Pharm</option>
                    <option value="M.Pharm">M.Pharm</option>
                    <option value="Pharm.D">Pharm.D</option>
                    <option value="B.Ed">B.Ed</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="program" id="program" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Program : CSE or ECE or B.Pharm or M.Pharm or B.Ed etc..." tabindex="5">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="year" id="year" min="2000" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Completion Year Of Graduation" tabindex="6">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Date of Birth : 1994-07-23" tabindex="7">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Mobile Number" tabindex="8">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control form-control input-lg" name="adress" rows="6" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group input-lg">

                    <label for="Status">Current Status :&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Working" onclick="doClick(this)">Working
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Self-Employed" onclick="doClick(this)">Self-Employed
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Studying" onclick="doClick(this)">Studying
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Home Maker" onclick="doClick(this)">Home Maker
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="textbox" style="display:none">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="org_name" id="org_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Organization Name" tabindex="9">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="designatin" id="designation" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Designation in your Company" tabindex="10">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><input align="center" name="alumniregs" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="11"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**dbconnection**

```
    if(isset($_POST['alumniregs'])){

        if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){
            $fname=$_POST['first_name'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){
            $lname=$_POST['last_name'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['roll_number'])){
            $roll=$_POST['roll_number'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
            $email=$_POST['email'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['SelectInstitution'])){
            $institu=$_POST['SelectInstitution'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['SelectInstitutiondegree'])){
            $insttidegree=$_POST['SelectInstitutiondegree'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['program'])){
            $program=$_POST['program'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['year'])){
            $year=$_POST['year'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['dob'])){
            $dob=$_POST['dob'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['mobile'])){
            $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['adress'])){
            $adress=$_POST['adress'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['optradio'])){
            $optradio=$_POST['optradio'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['org_name'])){
            $orgname=$_POST['org_name'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['designatin'])){
            $designatin=$_POST['designatin'];
        }
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $smt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `naik`.`aluminireg` (`fname`, `lname`, `rollno`, `email`, `Institution`, `degree`, `branch`, `year`, `dob`, `mobile`, `adress`, `presentstatus`, `orgname`, `designatin`,`date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'$date')");

        $smt->bind_param('ssssssssssssss',$fname,$lname,$roll,$email,$institu,$insttidegree,$program,$year,$dob,$mobile,$adress,$optradio,$orgname,$designatin);

        $smt->execute();
        $smt->close();

        if ($smt) {
            echo "<script>alert('Item Entered Successful')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**config**

```
<?php
    $dbconnection=array(
        'server'=>'localhost',
        'user'=>'root',
        'password'=>'java',
        'dbname'=>'naik'
    );
    $db=new mysqli(
        $dbconnection['server'],
        $dbconnection['user'],
        $dbconnection['password'],
        $dbconnection['dbname']     
    );
    //if($db!="null"){
    //  echo "<script>alert('connection Successful')</script>";
    //}
    if($db->connect_errno>0){
        echo "database connection error".$db->connect_error;
        exit;
    }
    //echo $db->host_info;
    #echo $db->connect_errno;
?>
```

Comment: try to found out error when data is not inserting

Comment: In which cases data aren't store into database? Any errors in app or database or error log?

Comment: Do:- `$smt->execute();
if ($smt) {
 echo "<script>alert('Item Entered Successful')</script>";
}else{
 printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
}
$smt->close();
` And check

Comment: what was the error when inserting a data into db ?

Comment: Adjust your code to following to find out what the reason is: `try { $smt = $db .... } catch (\Exception $e) { var_dump($e->getMessage()); }`. You probally have duplicate entries or you accidently SQL-Inject yourself without knowing and execute some errors (you should inform about SQL Injection / XSS and know that these exists for every user input)

Comment: Not a solution, but you bind every value - except date?  I know this is a value generated by you, but why not bind them all.

Comment: we cant bind value which is directly inserted by us it we give error

Comment: every statement in dbconnection is working fine but values are not inserted into db . even i had given echo statement after every statement every echo startment is excuted but only some times values are inserted in to db but not every time

Comment: we can ask your error if you not provided i can downvote for this now you say sometime insert and sometime not so its not a query problem its your data which you have passed in query...? share your error

Comment: @Bhargav it is not giving any error log man but data is not inserted into db if u want you can try plz but this is true

Comment: @CagatayUlubay hey i had wrapped code as u said but no errors are shown data is not stored in data base.

Comment: Did you also actually build up a connection to a database? Also  put them (or do an additional try/catch surround) in the try/catch too and look if the error comes from there. Also you shouldn't deactivate error_reporting if you did so.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay please go through config i had updated  connection to database file